# Unity MRTK: game view shows only white square

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I have a Problem. I installed and configurated MRTK for unity. I also installed three buttons in the scene in front of the main camera. When I start the game view with play, I only see a white square, none of the buttons. Can everybody say whats probably wrong? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK1H9.jpg)

Comment: Can you tell us, If your zoom in on the game mode, what happens? And also can you show the position values of the button in the inspector?

Comment: I fixed the problem! The buttons where at position 0,0,0 same as the camera. So i coud not the the buttons in the sceene.